# Trouble using lezhnev74/pasvl for PHP array validation

Tags: php, arrays, validation

Hopefully I'm not doing something silly here, but I can't get https://github.com/lezhnev74/pasvl to work as expected (error below).  I'd like to leverage the advanced array validation this github project provides.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
mkdir test
cd test
composer require lezhnev74/pasvl
```

PHP code (example code from the github readme) is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

use \PASVL\Traverser\TraversingMatcher;
use \PASVL\ValidatorLocator\ValidatorLocator;

$data = [
    [
        'type' => 'book',
        'title' => 'Geography book',
        'chapters' => [
            'eu' => ['title' => 'Europe', 'interesting' => true],
            'as' => ['title' => 'America', 'interesting' => false],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'type' => 'book',
        'title' => 'Foreign languages book',
        'chapters' => [
            'de' => ['title' => 'Deutsch'],
        ],
    ],
];

$pattern = [
    '*' => [
        'type' => 'book',
        'title' => ':string :contains(book)',
        'chapters' => [
            ':string :length(2) {1,3}' => [
                'title' => ':string',
                'interesting?' => ':bool',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$traverser = new TraversingMatcher(new ValidatorLocator());
$traverser->match($pattern, $data);
```

...and the error:

```
% php a.php

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of PASVL\ValidatorLocator\ValidatorLocator::locateDefault() must be an instance of PASVL\ValidatorLocator\object or null, instance of PASVL\Validator\AnyValidator returned in test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/ValidatorLocator/ValidatorLocator.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/ValidatorLocator/ValidatorLocator.php(22): PASVL\ValidatorLocator\ValidatorLocator->locateDefault('any')
#1 test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/Traverser/TraversingMatcher.php(216): PASVL\ValidatorLocator\ValidatorLocator->getValidatorClass('any')
#2 test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/Traverser/TraversingMatcher.php(128): PASVL\Traverser\TraversingMatcher->findMatchedPatterns(0, Array)
#3 test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/Traverser/TraversingMatcher.php(44): PASVL\Traverser\TraversingMatcher->matchDataToPattern(Array, Array)
#4 test/a.php(39): PASVL\Traverser\TraversingMatcher->match(Array, Array)
#5 {main}
  thrown in test/vendor/lezhnev74/pasvl/src/ValidatorLocator/ValidatorLocator.php on line 36
```

PHP version:

```
% php --version
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2017 18:08:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The author provided a fix, thanks Dmitriy!

Update composer.json:

```
"require": {
   "lezhnev74/pasvl": "~0.3.0"
}
```